# Compose: Check if an offset within an item in LazyListState is visible

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using `Jetpack Compose` for my `Android` application. I have a requirement where I have an `index` of an item and `offset`(Y coordinate) within that item. I need to scroll the list to that location, So, I am calling the below API and it is scrolling properly to the required location:

```
lazyListState.animateScrollToItem(index, offset ?: 0)
```

But, It is also scrolling when that offset is visible to the user. I need to scroll to that offset only if that offset is not visible. I tried to use the following API:

```
val layoutInfo = lazyListState.layoutInfo
Log.d("tag", "viewportStartOffset=" + layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset)
Log.d("tag", "viewportEndOffset=" + layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset)
```

But I see that `viewportStartOffset` and `viewportEndOffset` don't change while scrolling. Is there any way to scroll only if the offset within that item is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if item with specific index is visible and if it's visible you can check it's offset relative to start of viewport with `LazyListItemInfo.offset`

```
suspend fun safeScrollToItemWithOffset(
    index:Int,
    scrollOffset:Int,
    state:LazyListState
){
    val item: LazyListItemInfo? = state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == index }

    item?.let {
        // do some comparison with scrollOffset and offset of this item via it.offset

        // if true
        state.animateScrollToItem(index, scrollOffset)
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually need to check till how much offset an item is visible. E.g. if item 3 spans from 400 to 500 but is visible till only 450. I  need to scroll if my offset is 475. Is there any way I can get that offset value?

Comment: What do you mean by `E.g. if item 3 spans from 400 to 500 but is visible till only 450. I need to scroll if my offset is 475`? `LazyListItemInfo.offset` returns item's offset relative to start of viewport when it's contained inside `state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo`